# reactjs breadcrumbs function and too many renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a breadcrumbs component for my reactjs project and I keep getting errors for `Too many re-renders`. My `App.jsx` simply looks like this:

```
<div className="page-subheader">
    <Breadcrumbs />
</div>
```

The `Routes.jsx` looks like this:

```
export default [
    {
        name: 'Department1',
        abbrev: 'D1',
        icon: "fas fa-bullhorn",
        rootpath: '/dept1',
        paths: [
            {
                path: "/dept1",
                name: "Dashboard",
                Component: Dashboard,
                icon: "icon-Gaugage",
                showWelcome: true,
                crumbs: [
                    {name: 'Home', path: '/'},
                    {name: 'Department1', path: '/dept1'},
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "/dept1/mailroom",
                name: "Mailroom",
                Component: Mailroom,
                icon: "fas fa-envelope",
                showWelcome: false,
                crumbs: [
                    {name: 'Home', path: '/'},
                    {name: 'Department1', path: '/dept1'},
                    {name: 'Campaigns', path: '/dept1/mailoom'},
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "/dept1/people",
                name: "People",
                Component: People,
                icon: "fas fa-users",
                showWelcome: false,
                crumbs: [
                    {name: 'Home', path: '/'},
                    {name: 'Department1', path: '/dept1'},
                    {name: 'People', path: '/dept1/people'},
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "/dept1/tools",
                name: "Tools",
                Component: Tools,
                icon: "fas fa-chart-bar",
                showWelcome: true,
                crumbs: [
                    {name: 'Home', path: '/'},
                    {name: 'Department1', path: '/dept1'},
                    {name: 'Tools', path: '/dept1/tools'},
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Department2',
        icon: "fas fa-building",
        abbrev: 'D2',
        rootpath: '/dept2',
        paths: [],
    },
    {
        name: 'Deaprtment3',
        icon: "fas fa-users-cog",
        abbrev: 'D3',
        rootpath: '/dept3',
        paths: [],
    }
];
```

then the `Breadcrumbs.jsx` looks like

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from "../Utilities/Routes";


const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
    let location = useLocation();

    const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState(location.pathname);
    
    // going to default to the comms root for now
    const [currentRouteObject, setCurrentRouteObject] = useState({
        path: "/dept1",
        name: "Dashboard",
        Component: Dashboard,
        icon: "icon-Gaugage",
        showWelcome: true,
        crumbs: [
            {name: 'Home', path: '/'},
            {name: 'Department1', path: '/dept1'},
        ],
    });

    Routes.map((route, key) => {
        if (currentPath.includes(route.rootpath)) {
            route.paths.map((routepath, routekey) => {
                if (currentPath.includes(routepath.path)) {
                    setCurrentRouteObject(routepath);
                    return true;
                }
            })
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row align-items-center">
                <div className="crumbs">
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                        <ol className="breadcrumb">
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item"><NavLink to="/"><i className="icon-Home mr-2 fs14" /></NavLink></li>
                            {currentRouteObject.crumbs.map(({ name, path }, key) =>
                                key + 1 === currentRouteObject.crumbs.length ? (
                                        <li key={key} className="breadcrumb-item">{name}</li>
                                ) : (
                                    <li className="breadcrumb-item active"><NavLink key={key} to={path}>{name}</NavLink></li>
                                )
                            )}
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

I'm new to react but this all seems pretty straightforward-- I don't see why it's re-rendering the breadcrumbs component over and over.

Comment: first of all, DO NOT set a state in a `.map` method. create your final object then set that object in your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks are 'normal' JS functions (this is an important thing to understand). That function gets called by react every time when the state changes.

#### The Problem:

The Breadcrumbs component *is* a 'react hook'. The function is executed from top to bottom, and `setCurrentRouteObject(routepath)` changes the state. Because the state changes, Breadcrumbs is called again, so the state is changed again, so Breadcrumbs is called again, ...

#### Solution:

You should use `useEffect()` to change state depending on other state.

```
useEffect( function(){
    // ...
    setCurrentRouteObject(/* ... */);
}, [ currentPath ] );
```

There seems to be something wrong with how you use `Routes` here, I don't quite understand what should happen. You probably want have a look at the [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.